# How to drag a widget from your app to the home screen?

Tags: android

I want to improve my widget based app's flow for getting the widget on their home screen. I currently tell users to hold their home screen and add the widget. But I've used apps that let you drag the widget directly from within the app onto the home screen. I wish I could remember which app, sorry! If my memory serves it was one of google's apps. Anyway, how do you drag a widget from your app to the home screen?

Over the years I've googled this but always came up empty handed. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: "But I've used apps that let you drag the widget directly from within the app onto the home screen" -- name them!